# Time Invariance of Continuous Time System

Tags: continuous-signals, linear-systems

I am trying to check whether the system given by the following input-output relation is LSI or not?
$$y(t) = \cos(x(t)-x(0))$$
My work:

1. The given relation: $$y(t) = \cos(x(t)-x(0))$$
2. If the input applied is $x(t-t_1)$ $$y'(t) = \cos(x(t-t_1)-x(0))$$
3. Substituting $t = t-t_1$ in the given relation: $$y(t-t_1) = \cos(x(t-t_1)-x(0))$$
   From 2 and 3, One can see that shifting input gives the shifted output, i.e $y'(t) = y(t-t_1)$, but the system is not a shift-invariant system, Where I am going wrong?

Comment: Ooh.  Tricky.  I like your prof.  Try again with $x'(t) = x(t - t_1)$, and $y'(t) = \cos(x'(t) - x'(0))$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Apart from Tim's valuable hint in the comment, I'd like to point out that your work would be correct if the input-output relation were given by

$$y(t)=\cos[x(t)-\phi]\tag{1}$$

with some $\phi$ that is independent of the input signal. You treated the given equation as if the term $x(0)$ were independent of the input signal, which is of course not the case. I'm sure you can take it from here.